# How to split user stories in Azure Boards?

Tags: split, rally, azure-boards, user-stories

Is there a way in Azure Boards, at the end of a Sprint, whenever one US is not completed, to be easily split into 2 US - one to stay in the old sprint, and the other one to go to the next one?
For ex. such functionality exist in Rally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way - it is not integrated, but there is an extension in the Marketplace called Split!